# Copy and paste file to a different folder ENOENT

Tags: android, android-file

I've this android code for copy a file from a source to a destination:

```
private void move(File src, File dest) {
    try {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(src);
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                dest.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + src.getName()));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        is.close();
        os.close();

        // delete old file
        src.delete();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but i obtain ENOENT (no suche file or directory) warnint when i call

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(src);
```

and no file is copied.

This is a log with src and dst value

```
src: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20141026_183702.jpg 
dst:/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/destfolder
```

and this is warning message:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20141026_183702.jpg: 
open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

path is the same of src value!
What's wrong?

Comment: Hm. File not found? Or may be read external storage permission.

Comment: No. I've paste the warning. Permission for read and write storage ar setted.

Comment: "Pro-tip": for the dest File build use : new File(dest, src.getName());

Comment: "Pro-tip 2": Add a finally statement to the try catch. Close the in and out streams there but only if they are not null.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the error comes from the FileInputStream?

The FileOutputStream does not create directories. Use dest.mkdirs() before opening the streams this might solve your error.

Comment: The error is on FileInputStream, and directory exist. If i execute my code i obtain an empty folder.